# Error Proxy JMeter connection

Tags: java, proxy, jmeter

I'm in an enterprise and I use a special proxy, and when I want to launch my test, I've an error and I don't understand because yesterday I make a test and this test has succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Server is NOT in a position to accept the TCP connection request (Handshake) sent by the client (JMeter threads).

Connection Timeout can be caused by many reasons:

1. Server is not live, i.e., not running
2. Server is BUSY with serving other clients (Overloaded, and all server threads busy)
3. Proxy (which sits b/w client and server) is not forwarding the requests.

When Proxy is in place, client requests first hits the Proxy server and then take decision whether to forward the packet to the actual server.

Flow:

Request flow:

```
JMeter client -> Proxy 
Proxy -> Server
```

Response Flow:

```
Server -> Proxy
Proxy -> Jmeter Client
```

In your case, as it is failing in request phase itself, check the proxy settings applied by your organization. Maybe blocking the webserver that you are hitting.

So, go through the checklist and verify where the root cause is.

Following are some questions to help you in further debugging:

1. Is proxy settings mandatory to access the internet from your machine? How are you setting proxy settings in your browser to access the internet? (like specifying proxy ip, port OR specifying proxy configuration URL). please check the same in browser -> Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings in Connection section.
2. Are you able to access the server through the browser using proxy settings.
3. Do you try setting up the proxy settings in your JMeter?
   refer on how to run tests behind a proxy : http://www.testingminded.com/2010/04/running-jmeter-tests-from-behind-proxy.html

Comment: I think I enable to acces the server because in my enterprise I'm not alone to have this problem. If the problem persist I will come back. Thanks for your help :)